# python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, text-extraction

I am trying to install textract and am getting error messages> I'm using Anaconda so I tried:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple textract
```

I got the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4rh6j3p5\Ebo
```

I also tried:

```
pip install textract
```

and got the same error.

First I tried to upgrade setup_tools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

but it says it's already up-to-date

I also tried:

```
pip install ez_setup
```

but is says the requirement is already satisfied. I didn't think this would be the issue because I can use pip to install other packages, just not this one.

However, when I try to run ez_setup:

```
python ez_setup.py
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'
PS C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>
```

Which I'm not sure is related or not. I also tried:

```
easy_install textract
```

And got this error:

```
Searching for textract
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/textract/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/23/4d/0141a229be5edfc5d41efbf7757c050df9820cdee38eae67c08788269152/textract
-1.5.0.tar.gz#md5=29ac38f836a6e6146962d2d70505ffa5
Best match: textract 1.5.0
Processing textract-1.5.0.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-sd7jvx24\textract-1.5.0\setup.cfg
Running textract-1.5.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-sd7jvx24\textrac
t-1.5.0\egg-dist-tmp-d1fv4qbg
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found under directory '*'
creating c:\users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.5.0-py3.5.egg
Extracting textract-1.5.0-py3.5.egg to c:\users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Adding textract 1.5.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installing textract script to C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts

Installed c:\users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.5.0-py3.5.egg
Reading https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor/zipball/master
Processing dependencies for textract
Searching for SpeechRecognition>=3.1.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/SpeechRecognition/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/ce/0f/e14418e1797e3b6326618b3b4d1940734ed55878df64812784a7b6168eb5/SpeechRe
cognition-3.6.0.tar.gz#md5=00c6b126dc3494a71bcf57fb693e5644
Best match: SpeechRecognition 3.6.0
Processing SpeechRecognition-3.6.0.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-08mttkkw\SpeechRecognition-3.6.0\setup.cfg
Running SpeechRecognition-3.6.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-08mttkk
w\SpeechRecognition-3.6.0\egg-dist-tmp-w2rf0wr0
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
speech_recognition.__pycache__.__init__.cpython-35: module references __file__
creating c:\users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speechrecognition-3.6.0-py3.5.egg
Extracting speechrecognition-3.6.0-py3.5.egg to c:\users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Adding speechrecognition 3.6.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speechrecognition-3.6.0-py3.5.egg
Searching for EbookLib
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/EbookLib/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/04/30/2cbf65fa9587a1ecc66a78eea91f9189ead8fdadd5e009115bce34529aa6/EbookLib
-0.15.tar.gz#md5=d29882a04477c3854b1af9f6a84dc160
Best match: EbookLib 0.15
Processing EbookLib-0.15.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vcyqjzub\EbookLib-0.15\setup.cfg
Running EbookLib-0.15\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vcyqjzub\EbookLib
-0.15\egg-dist-tmp-ybq3stsw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 157, in sav
e_modules
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in set
up_context
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 255, in run
_setup
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 285, in run

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run
ner
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 47, in _exe
cfile
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vcyqjzub\EbookLib-0.15\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1671: character maps to <undefined>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==32.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 2270, in main
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 411, in run
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 674, in easy_install
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 702, in install_item
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 747, in process_distribution
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 846, in
 resolve
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1118, i
n best_match
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1130, i
n obtain
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 674, in easy_install
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 700, in install_item
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 881, in install_eggs
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 1120, in build_and_install
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", lin
e 1106, in run_setup
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 258, in run
_setup
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in set
up_context
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 169, in sav
e_modules
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 144, in res
ume
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 685,
 in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 157, in sav
e_modules
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in set
up_context
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 255, in run
_setup
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 285, in run

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run
ner
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-32.3.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 47, in _exe
cfile
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vcyqjzub\EbookLib-0.15\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1671: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

To start you could try running `pip check textract`which will verify any dependencies needed for the packed in question.

So it looks like you are running windows, which doesn't seem to be currently supported for textract. [See here](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#don-t-see-your-operating-system-installation-instructions-here)

You may need the following libraries, and maybe others as well.

1. `libxml2 2.6.21` or later is required by the `.docx` parser which
   uses lxml via python-docx.
2. `libxslt 1.1.15` or later is required by the `.docx` parser which users lxml via python-docx.
3. python header files are required for building lxml.
4. `antiword` is required by the `.doc` parser.
5. `pdftotext` is optionally required by the `.pdf` parser (there is a pure python fallback that works if `pdftotext`isn’t installed).
6. `pstotext` is required by the `.ps` parser.
7. `tesseract-ocr` is required by the `.jpg`, `.png` and `.gif` parser.
8. `sox` is required by the `.mp3` and `.ogg` parser.

You need to install `ffmpeg`, `lame`, `libmad0` and `libsox-fmt-mp3`, before building sox, for these filetypes to work.